# How could I implement logical implication with bitwise or other efficient code in C?

Tags: c++, c, performance, logic, algebra

I want to implement a logical operation that works as efficient as possible. I need this truth table:

```
p    q    p → q
T    T      T
T    F      F
F    T      T
F    F      T
```

This, according to wikipedia is called "[logical implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_implication)"

I've been long trying to figure out how to make this with bitwise operations in C without using conditionals. Maybe someone has got some thoughts about it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you need this for? Without context a discussion about efficiency is pretty much pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FYI, with gcc-4.3.3:

```c
int foo(int a, int b) { return !a || b; }
int bar(int a, int b) { return ~a | b; }
```

Gives (from objdump -d):

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   2:   0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
   5:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
   7:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
   a:   09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
   c:   83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
   f:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <bar>:
  10:   f7 d7                   not    %edi
  12:   09 fe                   or     %edi,%esi
  14:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  16:   c3                      retq
```

So, no branches, but twice as many instructions.

And even better, with `_Bool` (thanks @litb):

```c
_Bool baz(_Bool a, _Bool b) { return !a || b; }
```

```
0000000000000020 <baz>:
  20:   40 84 ff                test   %dil,%dil
  23:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  28:   0f 45 c6                cmovne %esi,%eax
  2b:   c3                      retq
```

So, using `_Bool` instead of `int` is a good idea.

Since I'm updating today, I've confirmed gcc 8.2.0 produces similar, though not identical, results for `_Bool:`

```
0000000000000020 <baz>:
  20:   83 f7 01                xor    $0x1,%edi
  23:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  25:   09 f0                   or     %esi,%eax
  27:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Or you could just use `gcc -S *.c; cat *.s` and skip the `objdump -d *.o` step?  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but I remembered the objdump option but not the gcc one :-p

Comment: Actually, testing gcc -S it gives /much/ more output, all of the extra stuff irrelevant.

Comment: I get much shorter code for the || version with _Bool (c99) or bool (c++)

Comment: this is insane. with optimizations off, the bitwise way stays that short, while the || way bloats all the way up :p

Comment: well, if you want fast code, it'd be pretty silly to compile without optimizations. I used -O3

Comment: @vasili111 Added. It was just a trivial type change of the first one.

Answer (score 16):

```
!p || q
```

is plenty fast.  seriously, don't worry about it.

Comment: who cares.. a bitwise operation will not be any faster than that.

Comment: Yes, actually I wanted to know also if this would be as fast as bitwise. Thanks for claryfing me that.

Comment: For a 32-bit int, "~p | q" does 32 times as much work as "!p || q" and doesn't require a jump.

Comment: litb: jumps are slower than arithmetic in just about every CPU due to branch prediction misses.

Comment: Great. Maybe you can edit your answer adding this info. I think is very interesting.

Comment: Agreed. I know I was unaware of it. Also, what do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: Chris, yeah that's what i was on. || sequences so that q is evaluated after !p in any case. tho if p and q are normal bools, chances are good that it compiles down to code as fast as ~p | q i think.

Comment: Dinah: By jump, I mean that the CPU has to decide whether to execute the next opcode or branch to another point in the program.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction

Comment: The bitwise operator is not 32 times as fast. It's one clock cycle per calculation either way. No difference in performance.

Comment: unless q is volatile, there is no need for a branch if both variables are simple integers.

Comment: eduffy: by 32 times as fast, I meant that you get 32 boolean results in parallel instead of one boolean result.

Comment: In addition to the potential branch caused by `||`, it also mandates a sequence point between the 1st and 2nd operand. This might in some cases work as a memory barrier, meaning that the compiler will not be able to re-order the instructions as it pleases. So it might very well be far less effective than bitwise `|` for that reason too. But all such micro-optimizations is an advanced topic and indeed nothing the average programmer should even begin to consider.

Answer (score 12):

```
~p | q
```

For visualization:

```
perl -e'printf "%x\n", (~0x1100 | 0x1010) & 0x1111'
1011
```

In tight code, this should be faster than "!p || q" because the latter has a branch, which might cause a stall in the CPU due to a branch prediction error.  The bitwise version is deterministic and, as a bonus, can do 32 times as much work in a 32-bit integer than the boolean version!

Comment: Thanks! I would like to ask where could I get more information about these? I mean about the C implementation of these operations, so I can get to know the details of || vs | and so on...

Comment: i've tested both versions. GCC at least on x86 insists on using a branch returning 0/1 for the bool version in every scenario i could imagine. bitwise ops did not.

Answer (score 5):

You can read up on [deriving boolean expressions from truth Tables](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A3868671) (also see [canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_(Boolean_algebra))), on how you can express any truth table as a combination of boolean primitives or functions.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for C booleans (a bit dirty, but works):

`((unsigned int)(p) <= (unsigned int)(q))`

It works since by the C standard, `0` represents false, and any other value true (`1` is returned for true by boolean operators, `int` type).

The "dirtiness" is that I use booleans (`p` and `q`) as integers, which contradicts some strong typing policies (such as MISRA), well, this is an optimization question. You may always `#define` it as a macro to hide the dirty stuff.

For proper boolean `p` and `q` (having either `0` or `1` binary representations) it works. Otherwise `T->T` might fail to produce `T` if `p` and `q` have arbitrary nonzero values for representing true.

If you need to store the result only, since the Pentium II, there is the `cmovcc` (Conditional Move) instruction (as shown in Derobert's answer). For booleans, however even the 386 had a branchless option, the `setcc` instruction, which produces `0` or `1` in a result byte location (byte register or memory). You can also see that in Derobert's answer, and this solution also compiles to a result involving a `setcc` (`setbe`: Set if below or equal).

Derobert and Chris Dolan's `~p | q` variant should be the fastest for processing large quantities of data since it can process the implication on all bits of `p` and `q` individually.

Notice that not even the `!p || q` solution compiles to branching code on the x86: it uses `setcc` instructions. That's the best solution if `p` or `q` may contain arbitrary nonzero values representing true. If you use the `_Bool` type, it will generate very few instructions.

I got the following figures when compiling for the x86:

```
__attribute__((fastcall)) int imp1(int a, int b)
{
 return ((unsigned int)(a) <= (unsigned int)(b));
}

__attribute__((fastcall)) int imp2(int a, int b)
{
 return (!a || b);
}

__attribute__((fastcall)) _Bool imp3(_Bool a, _Bool b)
{
 return (!a || b);
}

__attribute__((fastcall)) int imp4(int a, int b)
{
 return (~a | b);
}
```

Assembly result:

```
00000000 <imp1>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   39 d1                   cmp    %edx,%ecx
   4:   0f 96 c0                setbe  %al
   7:   c3                      ret    

00000010 <imp2>:
  10:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
  12:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
  15:   85 c9                   test   %ecx,%ecx
  17:   0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  1a:   09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
  1c:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  1f:   c3                      ret    

00000020 <imp3>:
  20:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  22:   83 f0 01                xor    $0x1,%eax
  25:   09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
  27:   c3                      ret    

00000030 <imp4>:
  30:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  32:   f7 d1                   not    %ecx
  34:   09 c8                   or     %ecx,%eax
  36:   c3                      ret
```

When using the `_Bool` type, the compiler clearly exploits that it only has two possible values (`0` for false and `1` for true), producing a very similar result to the `~a | b` solution (the only difference being that the latter performs a complement on all bits instead of just the lowest bit).

Compiling for 64 bits gives just about the same results.

Anyway, it is clear, the method doesn't really matter from the point of avoiding producing conditionals.

Comment: This is actually quite beautiful, and it reflects the fact that logical implication encodes the SUBSET OF relation on the powerset, and, (apparently) also the SMALLER THAN OR EQUAL relation on a poset. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

you can exchange implication to equel or less. it works
p <= q

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).